# How can i create a cloudwatch rule to trigger a lambda function every 15 minutes using aws cdk (JAVA)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a cloudwatch rule to trigger my lambda function using java aws cdk. I found something like below but it give me error.

Code:

```
Rule rule =
                Rule.Builder.create(this, "rule-" + id)
                        .schedule(Schedule.rate(Duration.minutes(15)))
                        .description("CloudWatch Event" + id)
                        .enabled(true)
                        .build();

        //rule.addTarget(alias);

        CfnEventSourceMapping eventSource = CfnEventSourceMapping.Builder
                .create(this, "EventSource")
                .functionName(lambda.getFunctionName())
                .eventSourceArn(rule.getRuleArn())
                .enabled(true)
                .build();
```

error:

```
Invalid request provided: Unrecognized event source, must be kinesis, dynamodb stream or sqs.
```

Please guide me here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your lambda created already but here is a working example where we create the lambda then add it to the cloudwatch rule so lambda will be triggered every 15 minutes.

```
Function lambda =
            Function.Builder.create(this, "my-lambda-name")
                    .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_11)
                    .code(LambdaCode)
                    .functionName("my-lambda-name")
                    .handler("handler_name")
                    .role(role)
                    .memorySize(3008)
                    .timeout(Duration.minutes(15))
                    .environment(LAMBDA_ENV)
                    .build();
    Rule rule =
                Rule.Builder.create(this, "rule-" + id)
                        .schedule(Schedule.rate(Duration.minutes(15)))
                        .description("CloudWatch Event" + id)
                        .build();

    rule.addTarget(new LambdaFunction(lambda));
```